# Specifying only one dimension and a build type out of two flavor dimensions when assembling in Android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on a multi-module Gradle Android project, which has two flavor dimensions and a build type. What I would want to achieve is build multiple build variants by **specifying only one flavor dimension and build type**. I will show you the flavor dimension setting part of my build.gradle.

build.gradle

```
...
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'adid', 'phase'

    productFlavors {
        full {
            dimension 'adid'
        }
        lite {
            dimension 'adid'
        }

        alpha {
            dimension 'phase'
            versionNameSuffix '-SNAPSHOT'
        }

        sandbox {
            dimension 'phase'
            versionNameSuffix '-SNAPSHOT'
        }

        beta {
            dimension 'phase'
            versionNameSuffix '-SNAPSHOT'
        }

        real {
            dimension 'phase'
        }
    }
}
...
```

As you can see, there are two flavor dimensions adid (2 flavors) and phase (4 flavors), and a build type (2 types), a total of 16 build variants.

1. assembleLiteAlphaDebug
2. assembleLiteAlphaRelease
3. assembleFullAlphaDebug
4. assembleFullAlphaRelease
5. assembleLiteSandboxDebug
6. assembleLiteSandboxRelease
7. assembleFullAlphaDebug
8. assembleFullAlphaRelease

Since our CI builds for a specific server phase at a time, what I would want to do is specify only one flavor and a build type in my gradle commands.

```
./gradlew assembleAlphaRelease // build for alpha phase
./gradlew assembleSandboxRelease // build for sandbox phase
./gradlew assembleBetaRelease // build for beta phase
./gradlew assembleRealRelease // build for real phase
```

I want assembleAlphaRelease to run both:

1. **assembleLiteAlphaRelease**
2. **assembleFullAlphaRelease**.

However, gradle does not let me do that. I can use any combination like one dimension, two dimensions, one build type two dimensions and a build type like below:

```
./gradlew assembleAlpha
./gradlew assembleFull
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew assembleRelease
./gradlew assembeFullAlphaRelease
```

But whenever I combinate one flavor and a build type, gradle gives me the following error.

```
Task 'assembleAlphaRelease' not found in project ':app'.
```

I am not sure if this is intended by the Gradle plugin or a bug but was curious if anybody could give me explanations why this is not doable. :)

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue where I have dimensions for different servers (Dev, QA, Demo, Staging, Release) and different white-labels of the app, and trying to do assembleQADebug is only building 1 of the white-lables in CI.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: Any solution to this?